# actionPerformed with JButton

Tags: java, arrays, jbutton, action, instanceof

I was just wondering how to get this JButton "nextButton" to work. It is used by the actionPerformed method for the e.getSource instanceof JButton. How can I make it to work alone?

```
        if(e.getSource() == nextButton){
            try {
                stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE seats SET type = 'booked' WHERE seatNum = 3");

            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton){
            bookedIcon = new ImageIcon("images/bookedSeat.png");

            int a = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
            int seat = a;
            a =- 1;
            seatsA[a].setIcon(bookedIcon);

        }
```

Comment: Please define "make it to work alone" -- what exactly are you trying to do? It's always best to explain the details of your code and your problem if at all possible.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask which details the way to ask a good question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Well, I have an array of buttons for which I use the if statement with instanceof, but i want the nextButton to change values in the db and go to another frame

Comment: Then go ahead and do that. You can put that code in the if block above, or you can give the JButton its own ActionListener, often an anonymous inner class.

Comment: Oh yeah, inner classes! Forgot about that, thank you! :)